# How to insert text without replacing anything in PHP

Tags: php, string, insert

How can I insert text into a PHP string at a specific point without overwriting anything?

Comment: Use substr_replace() with a length value of 0.

**CODE:**

    substr_replace("abcdefgh","bbbb",3,0);
The output of the above will be "abcbbbbdefgh"

Comment: I apparently can't reply to my own question.  I made this because I am a new programmer who tried to find this answer and saw a lot of silly responses when this is all that was needed.

Comment: This site is for Q&A... it's not for knowledge dumps/tips. Try submitting it as a comment to the PHP docs site.

Comment: can u give example on how u want to do?

Comment: @MarcB [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use substr_replace() with a length value of 0.

**CODE:**

```
substr_replace("abcdefgh","-bbbb-",3,0);
```

The output of the above will be "abc-bbbb-defgh"

Comment: This solution is simpler than using only substr and setting a new variable, as well as being less hardware-intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use `substr()`:

```
$str_a = "foo bar";
$str_b = substr($str_a, 0, 3) . ' baz' . substr($str_a, 3);
```